# uiimageview cabasicanimation disappearance effect

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, effect, cabasicanimation

I want the image gets smaller and smaller and disappears at the end. I could not achieve that with cabasicanimation. What should i use?

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
        anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        anim.duration = 1.0;
        anim.repeatCount = 1;
        anim.autoreverses = YES;
        anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
        anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.01, 0.01, 1.0)];
        [_tile1.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,

```
UIImageView *imgView;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imgView.transform, 0.1, 0.1);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
    imgView.image =nil;
    imgView = nil;
}];
```